# Make Material From Texture2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a program in unity. I'm quite new to unity, so i don't know much.i want to be able to make a new material in my code with only a texture2d to pass into it. So far im trying this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Search : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SearchEnter()
    {
        MyObject.GetComponent<Image>().material = LoadImage(name.ToLower());
    }
    Texture2D LoadImage(string ImageName)
    {
        string url = "file:///C:/MyFilePath" + ImageName + ".jpg";
        Texture2D tex;
        tex = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
        }
        return tex;
    }
}
```

I cannot do this as it cannot convert from texture2d to material. 
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are not **waiting** until the `WWW` request finishes so you are trying to access the result to early.

Instead of the `WWW` you should rather use a [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```
public class Search : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void SearchEnter()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadImage(name.ToLower()))
    }

    IEnumerator LoadImage(string ImageName)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file:///C:/MyFilePath" + ImageName + ".jpg"))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

            if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(uwr.error);
            }
            else
            {
                // Get downloaded texture
                var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);

                //TODO now use it

                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second issue: You can not simply convert a `Texture2D` to `Material`. You rather have to either create a new `Material` from a given shader or a given `Material` using [`new Material()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-ctor.html) e.g. using [`Shader.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.Find.html) like

```
//TODO now use it

// ofcourse again you can not simply create a new material from a texture
// you would rather need to pass in a shader like
var material = new Material(Shader.Find("UI/Default"));
material.mainTexture = texture;

MyObject.GetComponent<Image>().material = material;
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
```

However, for an `Image` you would actually probably rather simply stick with the default UI material but use a [`Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) instead

```
MyObject.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f);
```